# Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, webdriver

While running code in my eclipse(Selenium webdriver/java); but it shows error Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output".... [screenshot of code and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTpeA.jpg)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (‘**why isn't this code working?**’) must include the desired behaviour, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the version of Selenium you use isn't compatible with the version of Firefox you are testing. Make sure that you have the latest version of Selenium if you're testing the latest Firefox version, and set the *webdriver.gecko.driver* system property accordingly:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "c:\\tools\\webdriver\\geckodriver.exe");
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

For details, refer to the Mozilla documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette